# Get current path of windows explorer C++

Tags: c++, windows, path, window, explorer

i actually want to detect when a specific folder is opened on Windows, but after some research it seems that it is impossible. So, I want to get the current path of windows explorer, so i could compare it to the path of the folder in question, but I can't figure it out how to get this path... I only have this function but it gives me only the name of the folder.

```
string GetActiveWindowTitle()
{
    char wnd_title[256];
    HWND hwnd=GetForegroundWindow();
    GetWindowText(hwnd,wnd_title,sizeof(wnd_title));
    return wnd_title;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you figure this out? Having the same issue

Answer (score -2):

Delphi only. Translate to C++ by yourself.

```
function GetPathByExplorerHandle(AHandle: THandle): UnicodeString;

    function GetFolderIDList(AObj: IUnknown): PItemIDList;
    var
      PersistFolder2: IPersistFolder2;
      PersistIDList: IPersistIDList;
    begin
      if Succeeded(AObj.QueryInterface(IPersistFolder2, PersistFolder2)) then
        try
          if Succeeded(PersistFolder2.GetCurFolder(Result)) then Exit;
        finally
          PersistFolder2 := nil;
        end;

      if Succeeded(AObj.QueryInterface(IPersistIDList, PersistIDList)) then
        try
          if Succeeded(PersistIDList.GetIDList(Result)) then Exit;
        finally
          PersistIDList := nil;
        end;

      raise EOleSysError.Create('', E_NOTIMPL, 0);
    end;

var
  ShellWindows: IShellWindows;
  i: Integer;
  Dispatch: IDispatch;
  WebBrowser2: IWebBrowser2;
  ServiceProvider: IServiceProvider;
  ShellBrowser: IShellBrowser;
  ShellView: IShellView;
  ItemIDList: PItemIDList;
  ShellFolder: IShellFolder;
  ChildItem: PItemIDList;
  StrRet: TStrRet;
begin
  Result := '';
  OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLASS_ShellWindows, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IShellWindows, ShellWindows));
  try
    for i := ShellWindows.Count - 1 downto 0 do
      begin
        Dispatch := ShellWindows.Item(i);
        try
          OleCheck(Dispatch.QueryInterface(IWebBrowser2, WebBrowser2));
          try
            if WebBrowser2.HWND = AHandle then
              begin
                OleCheck(Dispatch.QueryInterface(IServiceProvider, ServiceProvider));
                try
                  OleCheck(ServiceProvider.QueryService(SID_STopLevelBrowser, IShellBrowser, ShellBrowser));
                  try
                    OleCheck(ShellBrowser.QueryActiveShellView(ShellView));
                    try
                      ItemIDList := GetFolderIDList(ShellView);
                      try
                        OleCheck(SHBindToParent(ItemIDList, IShellFolder, Pointer(ShellFolder), ChildItem));
                        try
                          OleCheck(ShellFolder.GetDisplayNameOf(ChildItem, SHGDN_FORPARSING, StrRet));
                          case StrRet.uType of
                            STRRET_WSTR:
                              begin
                                Result := StrRet.pOleStr;
                                CoTaskMemFree(StrRet.pOleStr);
                              end;
                            STRRET_OFFSET:
                              if Assigned(ChildItem) then
                                begin
                                  Inc(PByte(ChildItem), StrRet.uOffset);
                                  Result := UnicodeString(PAnsiChar(ChildItem));
                                end;
                            STRRET_CSTR:
                              Result := UnicodeString(AnsiString(StrRet.cStr));
                          end;
                          Exit;
                        finally
                          ShellFolder := nil;
                        end;
                      finally
                        CoTaskMemFree(ItemIDList);
                      end;
                    finally
                      ShellView := nil;
                    end;
                  finally
                    ShellBrowser := nil;
                  end;
                finally
                  ServiceProvider := nil;
                end;
              end;
          finally
            WebBrowser2 := nil;
          end;
        finally
          Dispatch := nil;
        end;
      end;
  finally
    ShellWindows := nil;
  end;
end;
```